# passing different vales of different buttons

Tags: android, button, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

i have 2 buttons on activity 1 (crime and health) having different onClickListeners and both functions leads to same activity 2...

on activity 2 i want to differentiate that which button user has clicked (whether crime or health) so the app could generate the respective msg..

i am using putExtra and bundle and also able to retrieve data from activity 1 to activity 2 but on activity 2 i am unable to understand what sort of if/else or switch statement should i use so i could differentiate which button is pressed by user

**ACTIVITY 1 - Minor**

```
    public class Minor extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    public String option;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.minor_view, container, false);
        Button ec = view.findViewById(R.id.ec);
        ec.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button hc = view.findViewById(R.id.hc);
        hc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Object view=null;
                buttonClicked( (View) view );
            }
        });

        return view;

       }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),HelpCall.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(option,"ec");
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

   public void buttonClicked (View v)
    {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),HelpCall.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString( option,"hc");
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

**Activity 2 - HelpCall**

```
    public class HelpCall extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_help_call );

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String ec = b.getString("ec");
        String hc = b.getString("hc");


        Button sms = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sms);

        sms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //   sendSms( "number", "Emergency.. " );
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "emergency call crime / health", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }

        });
    }

    private void sendSms(String phoneNumber, String message){
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say hc means Health and ec means Crime, then i would do something like this.
First you need to use one key to pass data to the second activity, let's say the key is "option", then in both your buttons write this, but in the third line change the second value based on which button was clicked ("ec" Or "hc")

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),HelpCall.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("option","ec");
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

now on the second activity you will get this value.

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String option = b.getString("option");
```

now in the on click listener

```
sms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 //sendSms( "number", "Emergency.. " );
 if(option.contentEquals("ec")){
    //crime clicked do thing here
 }
 else{
   //health clicked do thing here
 }
}
});
```

Comment: thanku @DaiwikDan ur answer was helpful....all i was not getting was how to send something regarding button to next screen.............so thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you basically want to put and fetch data from a bundle.

The idea is simple:

```
hc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),HelpCall.class);
              Bundle b = new Bundle();
              b.putString("option", "hc");
              intent.putExtras(b);
              startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

ec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),HelpCall.class);
              Bundle b = new Bundle();
              b.putString("option", "ec");
              intent.putExtras(b);
              startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

And in your second `HelpCall` activity you just need to get the passed value:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_help_call );
    String data = getIntent().getExtras().get("option");
}
```

This `data` string will contain either **ec** or **hc** depending on the clicked button in the previous activity.

---

There are also some improvements that you could do in terms of code coupling, I've written a couple of beginner articles that might help you out with this.

- [[AndroidBits] Passing data in Android](https://blog.joaquimley.com/androidbits-passing-data-in-android-6cec1917bdc)
- [[AndroidBits] How to decouple navigation between your components](https://blog.joaquimley.com/androidbits-how-to-decouple-navigation-between-your-views-4c50659379d9)

Comment: thanks @JaoquimLey ur answer worked well for me....all i was unable to solve how to send button info to send button info to other screen......thanks alot

Comment: If you think my answer really worked why didn't make it the accepted answer? =)

Comment: well that's because the answer which i accepted also answered me with my if/else problem to which i asked in question......both of ur answers were correct both worked for me but he gave me a sort of complete answer to my question

Comment: and no offence...please

Comment: Ofc I'm not offended hehe. Just curious. Also, the if / else statement is wrong, you should always be sure of what you are receiving, imagine your going to add another case, then your else will be wrong. Just a small tip.

Answer (score 0):

Change these things in your code

```
public String option;
```

To

```
public String option = "value";
```

And

```
 Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String emergency_type = b.getString("value");
    String call_type;
    if(call_type.equalsIgnoreCase("ec"){
              call_type= "ec" ; 
    }
      else{
         call_type = "hc";
       }

    Button sms = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sms);

    sms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //   sendSms( "number", "Emergency.. " );
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "emergency call " + call_type, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }

    });
```

Comment: thanks for ur quick reply @MayankBhatnagar but dont know why this gave me little errors on call_type........and i was so in my stuff that i didnt check what errors were there......
but now i read ur code and its call_type is not having any value coming from previous screen...rather its the emergency_type getting the value and call_type is here somehow irrelevent
.
but overall thanku so much for answering

Answer (score 0):

> i am unable to understand what sort of if/else or switch statement
>   should i use so i could differentiate which button is pressed by user

You can actually pass button id to next activity

Example in activity 1

```
 intent.putExtra("slot", v.getId());
```

In activity 2

```
int buttonId = getIntent().getIntExtra("slot", 0);
    switch() {
        case R.id.firstbutton:
            //Do what you want
            break;
        case R.id.secondbutton:
            //Do What you whant
    }
```